# How to change a color in of a specific int variable in c#?

Tags: c#

How to change the "x_req" color to Magenta for example, but not changing the "Requests" color?

x_req is a int variable if needed.

```
        string req_ = @"Requests: " + x_req;
        string treq_ = @"Total Requests: " + x_treq;
        string sucreq_ = @"Successful Requests: " + x_sucreq;
        string errs_ = @"Errors: " + x_errs;
        string time_ = @"Time elapsed: " + x_time + "s";

        Console.WriteLine(req_);
        Console.WriteLine(treq_);
        Console.WriteLine(sucreq_);
        Console.WriteLine(errs_);
        Console.WriteLine(time_);
```

Comment: Variables don't have color. Can you please [edit] question to clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

```
        Console.Write("Requests: ");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
        Console.WriteLine(x_req);
```

Use Write instead of WriteLine if you don't want to force a new line and change ForegroundColor before writing in that color.

Comment: @Ralf, about 9 minutes after your answer, and not knowing your answer, I posted my answer, and then deleted it.  I did not know Console.ForegroundColor was an option.  I just did a test in PowerShell and  `[System.Console]::ForegroundColor = [ConsoleColor]::Magenta ` changes the color of Write-Host, which behind the scenes uses Write and WriteLine.   Thanks!  FYI: Part of my answer was to possibly re-write in C# the Write-Host function found here: https://github.com/beatcracker/Powershell-Misc/blob/master/Write-Host.ps1